# In what situation we are forced to have only one instance in object oriented?

Tags: swift, singleton, object-oriented-analysis

As singleton design pattern is used to ensure only one instance of a class is created, I wander what problem would happen if we don't do so.
For instance, look at this example which is written in Swift.

```
let defaultFileManager = FileManager.default
```

Singleton patten is used here to ensure that only one instance of file manager is made.

1. My first question is what would happen if it wasn't designed with singleton and we could make several instances?
   Could an error occurred?
2. Is there a situation in which we are forced to have only one instance and by having more than one instance the program won't work fine?

Comment: Actually, `FileManager` is a bad example because you are actually allowed to create your own instances of `FileManager` in addition to using the singleton.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for your comment. could you please give a better example?

Comment: @Sweeper I don't see a reference for the `init` either but I know it can be done because I've done it. Also, read the paragraph under "Threading Considerations" in the reference docs for `FileManager`. *"The methods of the shared FileManager object can be called from multiple threads safely. However, if you use a delegate to receive notifications about the status of move, copy, remove, and link operations, **you should create a unique instance of the file manager object**, assign your delegate to that object, and use that file manager to initiate your operations."*

Comment: Suppose you had a singleton object that represents a single, shared physical resource, like an ethernet connection on a network card. What happens if you somehow make 2 of these singleton objects, and ask them to both transmit different things? Who wins?